# Publisher streaming is not working in Android 8 and greater version of Open Tok

Tags: android, opentok

I am using Open Tok for video Streaming purposes. My code and everything is working fine as expected, but the same application is not working in Android version 8 and greater. Not working means Publisher streaming is not getting rendered while I am receiving subscribers streaming and able to render that on view. Below is XML I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>               
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ll_main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
tools:context=".VideoCallActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPublisher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlPublisher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorTransBlack"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_view_height" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/publisher_container"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_view_height"
                android:padding="3dp" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/video_view_border"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_view_height"
                android:background="@drawable/video_view_outline"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivOutline"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_view_height"
                android:background="@drawable/outline"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPubName"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/empty_view"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pub_name_top_margin"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvPubName"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_very_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvPubName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:onClick="onClickSwipCamera"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivUser"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/video_view_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/video_view_height"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorTransBlack"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_list_height"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottom"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fabMenu"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu_colorRipple="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu_fab_size="normal"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/menu_bot_ico">


        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabMute"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:onClick="onClickMute"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:onClick="onClickAddParticipant"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_adduser"
            android:tag="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabChat"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:onClick="showHideChat"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabEndCall"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
            android:onClick="onClickEndCall"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cal_end"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorReject" />


    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_height"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/type_a_message"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/text_message_left_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_text" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/send_message_button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/send_message_button_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/send_message_button_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/send_message_button_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/send_message_button_margin_bottom"
                android:onClick="onClickSend"
                android:src="@drawable/send_ico"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hideChat"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_mic"
                android:onClick="showHideChat"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/llChat"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMute"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivMuteEarPiece"
                android:onClick="onClickMute"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mic"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMuteEarPiece"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_call_end"
                android:onClick="onClickEarpiece"
                android:src="@drawable/speaker_ico" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_call_end"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickEndCall"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cal_end" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivVideo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_call_end"
                android:onClick="onClickVideoOffOn"
                android:src="@drawable/video_ico"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAdd"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_icon"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_icon_margin"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_call_end"
                android:onClick="onClickAddParticipant"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_adduser"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And below is the Java code I am using to get publisher streaming.

```
mSession = new Session.Builder(this, API_KEY, SESSION_ID).build();
mSession.setSignalListener(this);
mSession.setSessionListener(new Session.SessionListener() {
         @Override
            public void onConnected(Session session) {
                mLogBusiness.insertGeneralLogToDB(TAG, null, null, "Initialized Open tok session", SESSION_ID, CONNECTION_ID);

                switch (type) {
                    case Constants.CALL_AUDIO:
                        mPublisher = new Publisher.Builder(context).build();
                        mPublisher.setPublisherListener(VideoCallActivity.this);
                        mPublisher.setPublishAudio(true);
                        mPublisher.setPublishVideo(false);
                        mPublisher.setName("" + pref.getUserId());
                        mSession.publish(mPublisher);
                        mPublisher.setAudioLevelListener((publisherKit, audioLevel) -> {
                            if (audioLevel >= 0.01f) {
                                Log.e("Glow", "publisher " + audioLevel);
                                ivOutlinePub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                ivOutPub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                ivOutlinePub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                ivOutPub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case Constants.CALL_VIDEO:
                        mPublisher = new Publisher.Builder(context).build();

                        mPublisher.setPublisherListener(VideoCallActivity.this);
                        mPublisher.setStyle(BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_SCALE, BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FILL);
                        mPublisherViewContainer.addView(mPublisher.getView());

                        mPublisher.setPublishAudio(true);
                        mPublisher.setPublishVideo(true);
                        mPublisher.setName("" + pref.getUserId());
                        if (mSession != null)
                            mSession.publish(mPublisher);
                        mPublisher.setAudioLevelListener((publisherKit, audioLevel) -> {
                            if (audioLevel >= 0.01f) {
                                ivOutlinePub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                ivOutPub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                ivOutlinePub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                ivOutPub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. App not crashing or not facing any error in error log

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time, I have figured out the solution. I added below code

```
if (mPublisher.getView() instanceof GLSurfaceView){
                            ((GLSurfaceView) 
mPublisher.getView()).setZOrderOnTop(true);
}
```

And it worked. It was happening due to z indexing order. And this worked for me.